# How do you avoid a spike being an implementation?

Tags: agile

The distinction between a spike and implementation is that the spike is designed to find things out, while the implementation is designed to make something that works.

In a spike you don't necessarily care about completeness, maintainability, correctness or ease of reading. But I'm finding, for some tasks, there is a tendency for a spike to be quite like an implementation.

Some factors that seem to be at play:

## "Real world" versus "construction"

I'm afraid that if I start "simulating" the situation too much the spike won't hold.

## Not liking hacks

I don't like hacks. The main reason is that I don't want to deal with the complexity of a bunch of hacks. Part of this is making tasks repeatable, so that I can quickly fix mistakes

## Interacting with existing tooling

Do people have any tricks or way of thinking about spikes in order to avoid this. For some stuff it seems easy, you can break off the task, implement it separately and it doesn't touch your code, or just easily break implementation off from the rest of your solution.

On trick I can think of is *get something running straight away*. This gets you into "spike mode".

Comment: Are you conflating _spike_ with _prototype_? I am not sure how you can end up with an implementation from a spike given that its objective is to figure out unknowns that are preventing you from actually implementing (or, at least, accurately estimating) the stuff you want to.

Comment: I think this could be a good question, but we need some more details about what your team considers a "spike" and what the desired output of that "spike" is.

Comment: I guess you are overthinking this.

Comment: @DocBrown I guess your underthinking this....

Comment: @VincentSavard Are you drawing an artificial distinciton between related concepts in order to avoid considering a question.

Comment: @AttRigh: to me, there is no such thing like a "spike mode". When I start writing a program, module, or simply add something to an existing program, in the first small iteration I seldom care about completeness, maintainability, correctness or ease of reading - instead I try to write something which works. But then immediately clean it up before ending the iteration (a.k.a. "refactoring"). I do this regardless if the program or feature will become a "spike" or something more complete - the only difference is to me how many iterations I do. ...

Comment: ... Devs who try to write code super-clean code without getting it work first, however, are blatantly violating the YAGNI principle. Devs, however, who try to write code which only works, and avoid to clean up (with the excuse of writing a "spike") delude themselves that this will be quicker. So I think one has always to find a balance, and if something ends up being a "spike" or not simply depends on the number of iterations one does. That's why I wrote "you are overthinking this".

Comment: I agree with @DocBrown: you are overthinking this topic. We want to do X, but we've no idea of the scope of work needed to achieve X. So we set aside some time to explore the topic. That's a spike. What comes out of a spike will range from "it can't be done" to "that was actually really simple. Here's the solution". If the spike results in a hacked together prototype, throw it away. If it results in more questions than it answered, you need a new plan. If it results in code good enough to PR, then great. Imposing rules that a spike must never be a solution is dogmatic and counter-productive

Answer (score 3):

The intention of a spike is to find out things. Sometimes you have to write code to find out things. Sometimes by the time you find out how to solve a problem, the problem is solved. Is that a problem?

Comment: Sometimes by the time you have worked out something is a bad idea you hae a fully implemented solution. Is that a problem?